# Оператор сравнения NOT IN

Tags: php, mysql

Допутим я хочу вывести новости из БД но не учитывая определенных пользователей. Пример:

```
SELECT news FROM posts WHERE id NOT IN (4,6,7...6000);
```

Вот в чем заключается вопрос, какова максимальная длинна выражения в скобках?
и как это будет сказываться на производительности БД?

P.S. пример выдуманный, и новости нужных пользователей я знаю как по другому вывести, мне нужно понять все насчет оператора

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Длина выражения в скобках не имеет значения.
Имеет значение длина запроса в целом.
Длина запроса задается настройкой max_allowed_packet в конфиге.

Comment: то есть: SELECT id,autor,date,category,title,alt_name,comm_num,descr,full_story,tags,symbol,fixed FROM `posts` WHERE id NOT IN (3....10000)
будет работать медленнее чем: SELECT id FROM `post` WHERE id NOT IN (3....10000)

Comment: Если запрос простой SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN(1...1000), да еще есть индекс по id и добавить limit, то запрос будет летать как пуля)

Вы можете ответить на свой вопрос, просто выполнив свои запросы и посмотреть на время.

Comment: @Andy Stark

> то есть: ... будет работать медленнее чем: ...

Запрос работает медленнее, не из-за длины запроса, а из-за перебора полей во время выполнения.

Comment: exeption, уже поигрался с запросами:) спасибо за помощь:)